# Heroku webhook custom authorization header

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to setup a webhook to notify a service when a release happened
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-webhooks

But I'm struggling to get authorization to work.
The docs say a -t flag will "A custom Authorization header that Heroku will include with all webhook notifications."

But there are no examples for the format, and I feel like I've tried everything.

I've tried:

```
-t <username>:<password>
-t "Basic <username>:<password>"
-t "Authorization: Basic <username>:<password>"
-t "Authorization: Basic <Base64 encoded username:password"
```

Example full command:

```
heroku webhooks:add -i api:release -u https://urltopostto.com -l notify -a someapp -t "Authorization: Basic <Base 64 encoded username:password>
```

But nothing has worked.
Does anyone know how to get the custom authorization header working

Answer (score 0):

`Basic <Base64(username>:<password)>`